# Does anyone know this book's title?

Tags: titles

Does anyone know this book's title?
It has different language explanations: English, Korean and I'm not sure what the other language is. Attached is a screenshot of the book.
I only have a chapter and would like to read the full book.
[image: book screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, this question will probably be closed as off-topic, since it's not directly related to the Japanese Language. It's possible someone who knows might answer in the comments though.

Comment: There you go: https://www.9640.jp/nihongo/ja/detail/?339　sample page: https://www.9640.jp/BOOK_PDF/9784874243398.pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not directly related to the Japanese language.

Answer (score 2):

The other language that you couldn't identify was Portuguese.

It looks like this is a Portuguese textbook of Japanese from a university course at the University of Porto: https://sigarra.up.pt/flup/pt/ucurr_geral.ficha_uc_view?pv_ocorrencia_id=349242

Note that section 4 on the page matches the Portuguese title on your screenshot: "4. Impressão, emoção de uma viagem".